# How to disable warning "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps" in a custom-hooks

Tags: reactjs, eslint

```
function SomeHooksOne() {
  const [state, setState] = useCustomState();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setState('SOME_VALUE');
  }, []); // The warning is occurred here.
}

function useCustomState() {
  const [state, setState] = useState('');
  return [state, setState] as [string, Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>];
}
```

ESLint: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'setState'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)

```
function SomeHooksOne() {
  const [state, setState] = useState('');
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setState('SOME_VALUE');
  }, []); // But the warning is not occurred here.
}
```

I'm a React Developer.
I fully understand this kind of warning.
I just wanted to disable the warning about this variable when I created a variable that does not change its reference value.

For example,

```
function useSomeEffectOne() {
  const [state, setState] = useCustomState();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setState('SOME_VALUE');
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
}

function useSomeEffectTwo() {
  const [state, setState] = useCustomState();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setState('SOME_VALUE');
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
}

function useSomeEffectThree() {
  const [state, setState] = useCustomState();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setState('SOME_VALUE');
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
}

function useCustomState() {
  const [state, setState] = useState('');
  return [state, setState] as [string, Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>];
}
```

How can I disable the warning for the setState() returned by the useCustomState() without using "eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhustive-deps"?

Comment: You can't, the "known stable" references are special-cased in the rule itself: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/9eb2aaaf8181743481bdce955ab3b5e9bbacac90/packages/eslint-plugin-react-hooks/src/ExhaustiveDeps.js#L153-L160. There's no mechanism to override that for custom hooks (only to add other hooks that should have their dependencies checked: https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/main/packages/eslint-plugin-react-hooks#advanced-configuration).

Comment: There's an open PR that would add a configuration option: https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/20513.

Comment: The warning has still occurred. Links are here. [example I found](https://recoiljs.org/docs/introduction/installation#eslint) and [repository link.](https://github.com/developer-choi/my-app) Do you know why the warning has still occurred?

Comment: What do you mean "still occurred"? After what? I'm saying it's **not** currently possible to configure the rule, so you have to disable it.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood that I can disable the warning if I add it to the additionalHooks option.

Comment: No, that _adds_ dependency checking to custom hooks, it doesn't add any stable references.